# How to solve $\Delta u(x) = 1, x \in \Omega $ where $\Omega = \{x \in R^3: a < |x| < b\}$ and $u = 0, x \in \partial \Omega$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve $\Delta u(x) = 1, x \in \Omega$ where $\Omega = \{x \in R^3: a < |x| < b\}$ and $u = 0, x\in \partial \Omega$. I tried to apply the fundamental solution of the laplace equation which reduces to $1 = \Delta u = v''(r)+\frac{n-1}{r}v'(r)$ where $r = |x|$. This gives me a solution $v(x) = \frac{c_1|x|^n}{n}+c_2\frac{|x|^2}{4-2n}$ then i tried to set up system of equations with respect to the boundary condition, but it seems impossible to solve, hence i think my approach is wrong... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that the equation is symmetric radially. However, you are solving the **inhomogeneous** Poisson equation $\triangle u=1$, rather than the homogeneous Laplace equation $\triangle u = 0$, therefore this is not the correct place to apply the fundamental solution (unless you are applying the Green's function method).

The correct way is as follows:

suppose $u = u(r)$, then using Laplace operator in spherical coordinate, you have
$$
\frac{1}{r^2}{\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}\right)}=1,
$$
which is nothing but an ODE, and you can solve it by, for example, Euler's Method, yielding the general solution
$$
u(r) = \frac{r^2}{6}-\frac{c_1}{r}+c_2,
$$
and then you determine $c_1, c_2$ by the boundary conditions.